# mysql => too many connection

Tags: mysql

I'm writing a program on Linux that needs to have lots of simultaneous connections. It's working fine for 150 connections but for more than that mysql gives this error:
"Too many mysql connections"

From [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html), apparently this limitation can be fixed. My question is that to what number I can increase the maximum number of connections?! How much RAM for each thread or connection?

Is pthread good enough for this application?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got a three-tier application (i.e. your application runs on some application server and users connect to it using either a browser or a dedicated client), then a [connection pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool) might help you.

The idea is to keep a pool of open connections and only take from that pool as needed and to return the connection to the pool as quickly as possible.

This way the actual number of open connections should be much lower than the number of active sessions/users.

Comment: Yes, But what if connections to server raises to more than the connections in the pool? (say 150)

Comment: @Hosi: Depending on the pooling software you use, you might be able to configure it for different behaviour: wait for a connection to be freed, when no more can be opened or return an error, for example.

Comment: "pooling software you use"? You mean library? Anyway thanks for answer, I'm going to test your idea! (with mysqlpp library)

Comment: Yes. Since you didn't specify which technology/language you use, I can't really suggest one.

Comment: @Hosi: just for clarification, could you post what kind of architecture you are implementing? By architecture I mean is it 2, 3 or a N-Tier aproach?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set max_connections more than 151 to login with user and password of your mysql server.

**set global max_connections = 15000;**

Answer (score 1):

Might connection pooling be of use? or does your application have to have 150+ connections open at the same time? I find it hard to belive that you need to have 150 concurrent connections. A bit more information on what you are trying to do would be helpful.

Comment: "I find it hard to belive that you need to have 150 concurrent connections", It's because I have more than 500 clients and each each one MUST to connect every minute for some seconds, so I 150 can happen although rarely!

Comment: @Hosi: that usually means you should be using a connection pool and keep your connections open as short as possible. We've been using that quite successfully and with roughly 10000 active sessions and about 300 connections at any given time then number of active DB connections rarely goes above 20-30 this way. So chances are you can easily avoid having 150+ open DB connections this way.

Comment: @Joachim: I assume that Hosi is implementing a 2-tier application. So connection pooling would be of little use.


@Hosi: What about moving to a 3-tier application?

Comment: @Chipmunk even with a 2-tier approach, simply adding retry logic to the client when this error occurs would help a lot, if the error case is a very rare one. Doesn't make sense to add too much architectural complexity just due to this error or enable too many connections on the db either. Of course there might be other good enough reasons to go 3-tier :)

Comment: @Chipmunk: I doubt it can help!

Comment: @Joachim: you might want to put your suggestion in as a possible awnser.

Answer (score 1):

Usually， `service mysqld restart --max-connections=500` will do the job for you.